# Is the Game Boy Advance SP charger dual voltage?

Tags: game-boy-advance

The GBA SP charger I have is from France. On it it says 230V-50Hz, does that mean that I can't plus it in the USA without a transformer (I have an adapter that is only converting the plug's pin shape).

Comment: What do you mean dual voltage?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, usually I think it'd be the adapter that would handle either voltage not the Game Boy itself. If your adapter says something like 120-230V - 50Hz then it can support both

Comment: Thank you! That's what dual voltage adapters usually say "110 - 240V". Only this one doesn't! I got another US one from eBay.

Comment: you can buy a "Voltage Converter" that will make 230v work on 110v mains

Comment: I thought about this... It turns out that a US adapter cost me less than 10 dollars and is also of Nintendo brand, therefore I chose to buy a Nintendo adapter rather than a third-party product. Thanks to all the people who answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the power adapter is specifically labelled as a 230v, it would be unwise to directly plug it in to a 110v plug, such as those in the USA.

You have the option to use a transformer to convert from 110v to 230v, or you could simply purchase another GBA power adapter in the United States.

I double checked on google and found [this post from 2005, on tomshardware.com](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/31594-13-using-gameboy-advanced-adaptor-Europe), from a user trying to do the reverse (American GBA in Europe).

The power adapters are different, but the connection to the GBA should be the same. If you can find a cheap power adapter in the states, it should already be regulated for 110v, and will work properly with your GBA SP.